# Разный вывод при попытке распечатать объект из двух разных мест

Tags: алгоритм, golang, графы

Здравствуйте! Есть граф, в котором узлами являются слова (тип **Word**), а ребрами - замены, превращающие одно слово в другое.
Например: между узлами `123` и `333` есть ребро `12->33`.

Есть метод, который ищет все пути от одного слова до другого и сохраняет их в **this.Path**:

```
func (this *Graph) FindPath(from Word, to Word, visited Dict, current Path) {
    if from.Eq(to) {
        if len(this.Pathes) == 0 {
            fmt.Println(current)
        }

        this.Pathes = append(this.Pathes, current)
        return
    }

    if visited.Index(from) != -1 { // если уже были в этом узле
        return
    }

    index := this.nodes.Index(from)

    if index == -1 {
        return
    }

    for r := 0; r < len(this.rules); r++ {
        index := from.Index(this.rules[r].Pat)

        if index == -1 {
            continue
        }

        this.FindPath(from.ApplyRule(this.rules[r]), to, append(visited, from), append(current, this.rules[r]))
    }

    return
}
```

После того, как этот метод закончит работу, в **this.Path** будут как правильные пути, так и не правильные. Добавим в **main** такую строчку:

```
fmt.Println(g.Pathes[0])
```

и сравним с выводом 4 строчки метода **FindPath**.
Получаем:

```
[{[1 0 1] [0]} {[0] [1]} {[1] [1 0]} {[1 0] [1 1]}]   // FindPath, правильный путь
[{[1 0 1] [0]} {[0] [1]} {[1] [1 0]} {[1 0] [1 1 1]}] // main
```

Не могли бы вы помочь? Могу выложить еще кода, но мне кажется, что ошибка именно тут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.FindPath(from.ApplyRule(this.rules[r]), to, append(visited, from), append(current, this.rules[r]))
```

Тут в цикле выполняется `append`. Допустим, что, сначала, в одном слайсе было что-то: (1)`[a, b, c]`. Потом к нему что-то добавили: (2)`[a, b, c, d]`. Потом попытались добавить что-то другое: (3)`[a, b, c, e]`. Однако слайс на втором шаге и на третьем должны храниться в одном и том же месте, поэтому первый **заменяется** на второй.

Нужно делать так:

```
new := make(Type, len(old))
copy(new, old)
append(new, element)
```

В то же время, мне не удалось сочинить пример, который бы это явно иллюстрировал. Буду благодарен, если кто-то предложит программку строчек в десять, из которой это будет однозначно следовать.
[Перевод](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/printing-one-and-the-same-object-in-different-places-gives-different-output/7638)